# Converting base 2 to Base 10?

Tags: binary

How is $0.11 \cdot 2^{1}$ converted to $1.5$ in base 10? I am unable to understand the theory behind this, since I believe $0.11 * 2^{1}$ corresponds to $1.1$ but I dont see the conversion process?

Comment: This notation is inconsistent. If $0.11$ is written  in base $2$, $2^1$isn't and it should be written $10$ in base $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0.11\cdot 2^1$ does indeed correspond to $1.1$. **In binary.** Which is to say, it means
$$
1\cdot 2^0 + 1\cdot 2^{-1}
$$
as per standard positional number system conventions. Writing this out in base ten does get you $1.5$.

Usually, when we write numbers in different bases close to one another, there is postential for such a misunderstanding. In those cases, it's common to see a subscript denoting which base we're using (this subscript uses base ten). So with that, the above paragraph would look like

> $0.11_2\cdot 2^1$ does indeed correspond to $1.1_2$. **In binary.** Which is to say, it means
>   $$
> 1\cdot 2^0 + 1\cdot 2^{-1}
> $$
>   as per standard positional number system conventions. Writing this out in base ten does get you $1.5_{10}$.

Comment: Thanks. One question, I see that indeed it is $1.1$ in binary, does the $2^{-1}$ come from the $.1$ after $1.1$ (1 after the decimal)?

Comment: When we write $1.1_2$, then that means one whole, and one half. This is how western positional number systems always work. The leftmost $1$ denotes the whole, and the rightmost $1$ (the one after the "decimal" point) denotes the half. This is entirely analoguous to how $1.5_{10}$ means _one_ whole and _five_ tenths.

Comment: Ack, so $0.00111_2 \cdot 2^2$ would be equal to $2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-3} = 0.875_{10}$?

Comment: @ysmflsd Yes, that's exactly what it would equal. $0.00111_2\cdot 2^2$ is equal to $0.111_2$, and you expanded that correctly, and then added them correctly together in base ten.

Comment: Great, thanks, I'l accept your answer once the system allows.